# Slicing with if condition and without

Tags: python, python-2.7

Consider this:

```
x="some_string"
z=[1,2,3,4] #list of four numbers
if x[z[0]-1:z[1]]==x[z[2]-1:z[3]]:
    print "Yes"
```

Same thing with slicing done before

```
x="some_string"
z=[1,2,3,4] #list of four numbers
a1=x[z[0]-1:z[1]]
a2=x[z[2]-1:z[3]]
if a1==a2:
    print "Yes"
```

Now why is the second method faster than first method?

What exactly is taking place here which is causing the second method to be more efficient than first?

**EDIT:**
This is a part of a big program which I was attempting at one of the sites. I was getting timeout error with method 1 with large inputs. Whereas the second method did it. It was at least 2 secs faster.The string length was 10000 for this scenario.Here are the two submissions:

http://hackerearth.com/submission/2129789   #Method 1

http://hackerearth.com/submission/2130107   #Method 2

Comment: How did you determine the second one is 'faster'?

Comment: I just ran `timeit.timeit()` on both and the second one is marginally **slower**, because you need to set and look up two additional locals.

Comment: I think your diagnosis is flawed, something else is different.

Comment: I also see the second as slower using `timeit`, testing with both 2.7.10 and 3.4.3 on Windows 7.

Comment: @vks: the 'close' vote mentions the reasons, and it's indeed a good reason to close your question as OT : the exemple you posted does not reproduce the described behaviour. Try to post with a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

Your diagnosis appears to be flawed. Using the [`timeit` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) you'll find that using addional locals is in fact *slower*, but only by the smallest of margins.

I reduced your tests to the essentials to reduce overhead:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> def f1(x="some_string", z=(1, 2, 3, 4)):
...     x[z[0] - 1:z[1]] == x[z[2] - 1:z[3]]
... 
>>> def f2(x="some_string", z=(1, 2, 3, 4)):
...     a1 = x[z[0] - 1:z[1]]
...     a2 = x[z[2] - 1:z[3]]
...     a1 == a2
... 
>>> timeit(f1)
0.6033928394317627
>>> timeit(f2)
0.6054778099060059
```

The difference is so small as to be negligible. If you run this often enough `f2` can win by the same margin. If you reverse the tests (run `f2` first, then `f1`), the outcomes change again. That's because there is practically no difference.

The two functions execute the exact same bytecodes, with the addition of two `STORE_FAST` and `LOAD_FAST` opcodes for `f2` at indices 22, 47, 50 and 53.

```
>>> dis.dis(f1)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (z)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              9 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             10 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             13 BINARY_SUBTRACT     
             14 LOAD_FAST                1 (z)
             17 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             20 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             21 SLICE+3             
             22 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             25 LOAD_FAST                1 (z)
             28 LOAD_CONST               3 (2)
             31 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             32 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             35 BINARY_SUBTRACT     
             36 LOAD_FAST                1 (z)
             39 LOAD_CONST               4 (3)
             42 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             43 SLICE+3             
             44 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             47 POP_TOP             
             48 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             51 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(f2)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (z)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              9 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             10 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             13 BINARY_SUBTRACT     
             14 LOAD_FAST                1 (z)
             17 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             20 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             21 SLICE+3             
             22 STORE_FAST               2 (a1)

  3          25 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             28 LOAD_FAST                1 (z)
             31 LOAD_CONST               3 (2)
             34 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             35 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             38 BINARY_SUBTRACT     
             39 LOAD_FAST                1 (z)
             42 LOAD_CONST               4 (3)
             45 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             46 SLICE+3             
             47 STORE_FAST               3 (a2)

  4          50 LOAD_FAST                2 (a1)
             53 LOAD_FAST                3 (a2)
             56 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             59 POP_TOP             
             60 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             63 RETURN_VALUE
```

The `STORE_FAST` and `LOAD_FAST` copy across a pointer between the stack and the locals array, both pre-allocated structures. So `f2` is doing the teensiest more work than `f1` is doing. Changing the sizes of the inputs is not making a difference here, a pointer doesn't get 'heavier' if the referenced object is bigger.

Comment: See here https://www.hackerearth.com/submission/2129789/ https://www.hackerearth.com/submission/2130107/

Comment: For the last two cases check the times

Comment: @jonrsharpe check the links posted

Comment: You cheated with the times! ;-)

Comment: @KlausD.: I reconstructed the session and got my copies and pasting mixed up.

Comment: @vks whatever hackerearth reports a fact is a fact: the second version is constantly (if marginally) slower than the first, so either you didn't get the same inputs or you changed something else in your code or hackerearth's timings are flawed.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers this is tested with a small input.Maybe with large inputs it differs?

Comment: @vks: it doesn't matter how large the inputs are; the *bytecode* won't change.

Comment: @vks: and the bytecode for `f2` executes 4 extra opcodes. The only other difference is a marginal difference in how the stack is used, but the stack is just references. One extra stack slot being used won't change how much memory needs to be allocated here, but you do need to allocate 2 extra slots for local memory.

Comment: @vks: it's _your_ duty to provide an example that reproduces the behaviour. We tested with _your_ example code, and it does _not_ reproduce the behaviour you mention.

Answer (score 1):

If you examine your results a little more closely on the linked hackerearth site you will see that, individually, the first method is quicker on most of the inputs. What happened is that the last two results (for inputs 7 and 8) didn't complete in a timely fashion, which resulted in an overall longer runtime. Why is anyone's guess, maybe the server was under heavy load at that time and your process had a low priority.

Comment: I have been running with method 1 for 2 days.So server under heavy load might not be true.But yes both the inputs 7 and 8 are `bbbb` 10000 times.Is that making any difference?

Comment: Thanx for the input.I was overlooking the point that with rest method 1 was taking shorter time.